# PKCS7 Padding in JavaCard

Tags: padding, smartcard, javacard, pkcs#7

I am trying to implement my own PKCS7 padding scheme in JavaCard environment in case a smart card does not support PKCS5 or 7 padding schemes.

I want the block size of the PKCS padding scheme to be flexible in the event that different block size of symmetric ciphers are used. The `length` indicates the message input length and the `blocksize` indicates the size of a cipher's block.

My algorithm would check two scenarios in the PKCS7 padding namely if all bytes are the same bytes (e.g. `0A, 0A, 0A .. 0A, 0A, 0A`) which means there is no padding involved and would return a value `0`.

The second scenario is the checking if there is padding (e.g. `0A, 0B, 0C, 05, 05, 05, 05, 05`).

I am able to check all the scenarios successfully but when it comes to copying the data to output the result, it doesn't seem to copy correctly.

It seems like the `arrayFillGenericNonAtomic()` data that was filled before the `arrayCopyRepackNonAtomic()` is called is still stuck in the output byte array and doing the `arrayCopyRepackNonAtomic()` is not copying the data properly.

The output byte array format I am using is for the first element in the array to carry the indicator (in byte representation) of the amount of data that has been processed for output (e.g. `output[outputOffset] = (byte) 0x10` means 16 data element afterwards that has been processed). Subsequent data elements in the output byte array after the first element contains the processed data.

An example of the problem is I am trying to PKCS7 decode `A0, B0, C0, D0, E0, 04, 04, 04, 04` and the outcome should be `05, A0, B0, C0, D0, E0` (where the 05 represents following 5 bytes are processed) but I am getting `05, 04, 04, 04, 04 ..` instead.

How do I fix the problem of the `arrayCopyRepackNonAtomic()` not working as expected ?

I am testing the code on an actual JavaCard 2.2.2 and JavaCard 3.0.4 compatible smart card that is in OP_READY mode.

```
public static void process(byte[] input, short offset, short length,
        short blockSize, byte[] output, short outputOffset, short mode) {
    if (mode == MODE_DECODE) {
        // Data length must be >= blocksize and have to have be a modulus of 0 size.
        if ((length >= blockSize) && ((length % blockSize) == 0)) {
            output[outputOffset] = (byte) length;
            ArrayLogic.arrayFillGenericNonAtomic(output, (short) (outputOffset + 1), (short) (length - 1), output, outputOffset);
            if (ArrayLogic.arrayCompareGeneric(input, offset, output, outputOffset, length) == 0x00) {
                // If all bytes are the same, return 0.
                output[outputOffset] = (byte) 0x00;
            } else {
                // Bytes are not all the same, check if the last segment of bytes are padded.
                if (ArrayLogic.arrayCompareGeneric(input, offset, output, outputOffset, (short) (input[(short) (offset + length - 1)] & 0xFF)) == 0x00) {
                    // Padded bytes are found.
                    output[outputOffset] = (byte) (length - input[(short) (offset + length - 1)]);
                    // Unable to copy correctly to output
                    ArrayLogic.arrayCopyRepackNonAtomic(input, offset, (short) (output[outputOffset] & 0xFF), output, (short) (outputOffset + 1)); 
                } else {
                    output[outputOffset] = (byte) length;
                    // Unable to copy correctly to output
                    ArrayLogic.arrayCopyRepackNonAtomic(input, offset, length, output, (short) (outputOffset + 1));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The question have been solved and the problems are wrong variable offsets and also handling of byte to short conversions that caused the problem.

Below is a working version that seems to does the padding after some testing for those interested in using it in the future.

```
public static void process(byte[] input, short offset, short length,
        short blockSize, byte[] workBuff, short buffOffset, byte[] output,
        short outputOffset, short mode) {
    if (mode == MODE_DECODE) {
        // Data length must be >= blocksize and have to have be a modulus of 0 size.
        if ((length >= blockSize) && ((length % blockSize) == 0)) {
            workBuff[buffOffset] = (byte) input[(short) (length + offset - 1)];
            ArrayLogic.arrayFillGenericNonAtomic(workBuff, buffOffset, length, workBuff, buffOffset);
            if (ArrayLogic.arrayCompareGeneric(input, offset, workBuff, buffOffset, length) == 0x00) {
                // If all bytes are the same, return 0.
                output[outputOffset] = (byte) 0x00;
            } else {
                output[outputOffset] = (byte) (offset + length - (workBuff[buffOffset] & 0xFF));
                output[(short) (outputOffset + 1)] = workBuff[buffOffset];
                // Bytes are not all the same, check if the last segment of bytes are padded.
                if (ArrayLogic.arrayCompareGeneric(input, (short) (offset + length - (workBuff[buffOffset] & 0xFF)), workBuff, buffOffset, (short) (workBuff[buffOffset] & 0xFF)) == 0x00) {
                    // Padded bytes are found.
                    output[outputOffset] = (byte) (length - input[(short) (offset + length - 1)]);
                    ArrayLogic.arrayCopyRepackNonAtomic(input, offset, (short) output[outputOffset], output, (short) (outputOffset + 1));
                } else {
                    // Padded bytes are not found.
                    output[outputOffset] = (byte) length;
                    ArrayLogic.arrayCopyRepackNonAtomic(input, offset, length, output, (short) (outputOffset + 1));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are exact input values (`length`, `blockSize`) for output `05, 04, 04, 04, 04 ..`?

Comment: General recommendation: do not use `ArrayLogic` "repack" methods for tasks you can easily handle with `javacard.framework.Util`. `ArrayLogic` methods are far more powerful than `Util` methods, but there is no reason to use them for these very simple purposes - `Util` methods are more readable and have better performance.

Comment: I just noticed when I call the methods, the input and output byte arrays are the same so it gets mixed up and overwritten so now I added an additional byte array as a intermediate buffer which seems to settle part of the problem. The original post codes are not updated yet as @Paul Bastian's answer seems to be interesting and I am looking at it for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, I don't think thats the only mistake, but your branch is definitly wrong:

```
// Bytes are not all the same, check if the last segment of bytes are padded.
if (ArrayLogic.arrayCompareGeneric(input, offset, output, outputOffset, (short) (input[(short) (offset + length - 1)] & 0xFF)) == 0x00) {
```

You are comparing the right length, but the wrong offsets.

I'm not understanding what the else-case should do in your method. Should throw an error if the padding was wrong?

Comment: else case handles the scenario where you have 0A, 0B, 0C, 0D, 08, 08, 08, 07, 08, 08, 08, 08. The last 8 bytes looks almost like a 08 pad but due to a 07 it is not considered a pad so the else clause catches that and declares it not a proper pad and simply returns the input results as the output without modification.

Comment: Yes, part of the problem was wrong variables used for offsets and many other small little problems bugging the function. I will update the question to contain the actual working answer.

Comment: Another main problem of the old codes I wrote assumes the input and output to be two different byte arrays and these arrays can be re-used as working buffers to manipulate data but that's not always the case so I added a specific working buffer byte array for segregating buffer computations from input/output which is part of the many problems the old functions have.